# 405 method not allowed using $http service AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-405

I'm getting a 405 error making a request from localhost, this is the full error:

> OPTIONS http://www.myurl.com 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.myurl.com. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

I understand the problem but the quirk is that I get this error just when I use the angular $http service:

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.myurl.com',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
    }
}

$http(req)
    .then(function(res) {},
        function(error) {});
```

Using XMLHttpRequest works perfectly:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", 'http://www.myurl.com', true);
xhttp.send();
```

I have a chrome extension to add CORS headers and it is working. I also notice that if I remove the third parameter in xhttp.open the error appears again.

¿Does anyone know the reason? ¿How can I use the angular services without get the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this. Because you are not sending any parameter to the url. So I think this is a good way to do this. just try it may work for you.

```
$http.post('http://www.myurl.com').
success(function(data) {
     //success Response here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow OPTIONS method on your server side. Before every GET, POST, PUT, DELETE... requests an OPTIONS request is launched.

I advise you to disable your "chrome extension to add CORS", to have the same configuration of your final users.